# New File System drivers for ubuntu

Tags: filesystem, files, ubuntu-drivers

I have done some kernel development previously, simple ones really. I wanted to know what direction I should be looking in to create a custom files system of my own. Most things I have found with a simple search has not provided and direct answer of suggestions. Any help in this matter will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow! Cool!

**Short answer**

The easiest file system around is FAT16, so I would download the source code for that and start messing in there.

**Long answer**

Could you elaborate a bit on what you're trying to accomplish here?  I mean: File systems are at the rather low end of the development spectrum ("Low" = "Low-level, high in complexity").

**Edit after comment**

In case of an encrypted file system, I would download the latest "TrueCrypt source code" out there (first link in google at the time of this writing) and start from there!

Comment: Thanks!! that sounds like like a good starting point. As far as what I am trying to accomplish. I would like to create a encrypted FS, that I can integrate with Ubuntu and other variants. I will be making it open source.    Side note: I have not done any ASM programming in a while so I hope my C/C++ will suffice.

Comment: Upvoting my answer is considered a "thank you" on this forum...  No need to write comments!  ;) You upvote by clicking the grey arrow above the number next to my answer which currently reads "0"